# Switch Image Acording To Custom Options

Tags: javascript, image, custom-options, php-5.4

I would like to be able to let my clients select the product they want using a thumbnail defined in Custom Options.

If I have "White" selected in my dropdown menu. I would like the product image to update to the white image.

I know there are modules for this, however I would appreciate a free option if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The one (free) extension I have used to do this was:

https://github.com/organicinternet/magento-configurable-simple

The one main feature is:

> In addition it can optionally change the product's image, associated image gallery, name and description to match the associated product when a user has made their selection of a product's configurable options. (so if a user has chosen a silver phone they can see it in silver before they buy it)

However, this would force use to use configurable products that link to simple products (the simple products would have a picture set to them so it knows what to change).

There are a few paid modules that do it more elegantly, however you just wanted a free extension reference.